# How to read only specified column with R?

Tags: r

i'm trying to load a csv file. But I only need certain columns, i don't need all

This works

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("C:/test.csv", nrows=1000, select=c(1,3,5))
```

But I want to choose columns by their names, and not their sequential numbers. How can I do this?

```
 #this does not work
 dt <- fread("C:/test.csv", nrows=1000, select=c(col1,col3,col5))
```

Comment: You can set the `colClasses` vector for all other columns (which you don't want) to `"NULL"`

Comment: The file contains over 1000 columns. I need to choose only 50 of them. Is there any way to specify what i need, rather then what i don't/ Thank You!

Comment: Looking into the documentation, you can just supply the relevant (50) column names to the `select` argument. "select: Vector of column names or numbers to keep, drop the rest."

Comment: Yeah you just need to put the names in quotes, otherwise it will think they are objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the sqldf package:

```
library(sqldf)

dt <- read.csv.sql(file = file.choose(), sql = "SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln FROM file", header = TRUE)
```

Where col1, col2, ..., coln are your desired columns, and file = the file you choose from your directory.